# Excel - How to count number of rows above cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic, range, self-reference

I am trying to create a single-column dynamic range and refer to it in the same column but all examples google throws up use the entire column, with  the referencing cell in a separate column.

I will be adding values as table rows and it is painstaking to have to update ranges every time the table is altered.

Is there a way to use formulas to count the number of rows above a particular cell? ie a COUNT() equivalent of SUM(ABOVE).

I can't believe it is so difficult to self-reference a cell with this software.

Comment: I hope the linked duplicate is what you are after. If not, get back to me here and we can reopen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was unaware of the let function and I'm sure I will put it to use moving forward. However, the issue remains - In your supplied answer, the filter formula is given the explicit range B1:B5. I need a way to make this range dynamic ie I don't know ahead of time whether row 5 will be the maximum row number. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please include more details in your question above including sample data with desired output. Btw, `LET()` was not the function I wanted to emphasize. Look at `VSTACK()`. Can you explain how this issue remains?

Comment: Apologies I hit return halfway through typing my response. It has now been edited.

Comment: Maybe it will help to apply `FILTER()` and only return an array that is not empty? Something like `=FILTER(B:B,B:B<>"")` and then load that into `LET()` and use `VSTACK()` as per example. Without more proper sample data is becomes a bit hard to guide you further.

Comment: Formula to return the desired output should be equivalent to =COUNT(ABOVE). I don't know how to simplify this further.

Comment: Are you manually inserting rows above the formula? If so, maybe `=COUNT(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1))`. This is a bit of a long shot though but assuming you manually include new data this formula will take into account the entire range above itself.

Comment: Ill make it an answer for you to close the thread then.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to be able to add/remove lines in the data above the said formula. Therefore try:

```
=COUNT(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,ROW()-1))
```

Comment: Sir, does this works the same way like the above as well, correct me If i am wrong `=COUNT(TAKE(A:A,1):TAKE(A:A,-1))`

Comment: It worked @MayukhBhattacharya, was unexpected for me. Nice find. I suppose the mechanics behind `TAKE()` must be similar to `INDEX()` in regards to allowing the range construct with the colon.

Comment: Sir that I realised on the other query, that using `TAKE()` we can take row(s) from top and row(s) from bottom, so thought of this one and applied, but if i apply the formula below the data, it is not working like the one with `INDEX()`